# Not getting complete data using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am not getting all links there are `403 links` in these page I am getting only `68 links` I also used the scroll down method they move to end of page but not give all links is any thing I am doing wrong kindly guide us these is page link https://www.ocado.com/search?entry=frozen

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
url='https://www.ocado.com/search?entry=frozen'
PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver =webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get(url)
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 50
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
    
t=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='fop-contentWrapper']")
for l in t:
    links= l.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//a[starts-with(@href, '/products')]").get_attribute("href")
    print(links)
```

Comment: Sorry for the question, can be done in playwright instead of selenium? Or it must be selenium yes or yes?

Comment: why selenium is not working for these.. ?

Comment: Going down to the end of the page does not load the entire page. There is usually a limit where there are multiple boxes. If you are at the bottom of the page, that limit of boxes is loaded at the same time.Instead of going to the bottom of the page and getting the links once, if you go down in 10 pieces on the page and get the links each time and add them to a list, you can reach as many products as you want. (There will be duplicate data in the page as you will get the links again. You can convert it to a pandas table and use the drop_duplicate method for this.)

Answer (score 1):

With this should be enough:

```
# Needed libs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

# We create the driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# We maximize the window, because if not the page will be different
driver.maximize_window()

# We navigate to the url
url='https://www.ocado.com/search?entry=frozen'
driver.get(url)

# We click on acceptbutton cookies pop up
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']"))).click()

# We take the show_more_button, which is at the bottom
show_more_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Show more']")

# We take latest product which contain the info we want, that product will be more or less in the middle of the page because it is the latest one which is loaded
last_element_with_link = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='fop-contentWrapper']/a[last()]")))

# If the location of the show_more_button - last_element_with_link location is bigger than 500 px means we did not arrive till the end of list
while show_more_button.location['y'] - last_element_with_link.location['y'] > 500:
    # We get the location of the new last_element_with_link because we should have more elements
    last_element_with_link = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='fop-contentWrapper']/a[last()]")))
    # We do till we arrive to the position of this new last_element_with_link
    print(f"Scroll to px: {last_element_with_link.location['y']}")
    driver.execute_script(f"window.scrollTo(0, {last_element_with_link.location['y']})")
    # small sleep to give time to the page
    time.sleep(0.1)

# Here we now we are at the botton, so we can take the links
list_of_elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='fop-contentWrapper']/a")))
print(len(list_of_elements))
# For each element we print the url
for element in list_of_elements:
    print(element.get_attribute('href'))
```

Actually there are 403 products per page

Comment: Instead of hard coded range you can user infinite loop and then check the length of the total product elements if there is no further elements then break. Anyways good solution. +1

Comment: ok thank for helping ....last question ......they will scroll to much fast how to apply wait on scroll that they will scroll slowly the product are properly loaded.....

Comment: they give me total 76 products....how much total product they give you...

Comment: That is much more complex because that page loads by javascript, so you have to give to the page a time to load that javascript. I got 403 products. Did you remove the time.sleep?

Comment: NO I did not remove time to sleep...

Comment: Okay, I edited with a new approach, if is not valid, you have to set higher time.sleep

Comment: they show 403 products but they give 80 links .....

Comment: I have set time.sleep to 2 but again give 80 links....

Comment: I am thinking selenium is not suitable for these.............

Comment: it gives you all 403 product link you apply length to check......?

Comment: Yep, with the exact code from my answer I'm getting 403 products.